# Google App Engine Won't Save Wordpress Theme Settings on Localhost or Production Server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-app-engine

I'm running Apache and MySQL via XAMPP v1.8.2 to support a WordPress site for Google App Engine (GAE) local development and cloud deployment using GAE SDK v1.8.8.

Changing settings or stylings of the theme, which uses AJAX, does not save on the local server or the production server.  The theme's settings and stylings though can be changed on a localhost not using GAE.

I've tried repairing and reinstalling GAE, WordPress and XAMPP so I reason it may be my server / DB setup or a GAE issue.

Launching the app via GAE Launcher's log displays the following error:

> 2013-12-26 09:30:03 Running command: "['C:\Program
>   Files\Python27\python.exe',
>   'C:\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py',
>   '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=9080', '--admin_port=8001',
>   'C:\catalyx-GoogleAppEngine\catalyx']" 2013-12-26 09:30:03 (Process
>   exited with code -1073741515)

The site's app.yaml contains:

```
application: catalyx-wp
version: wp
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: wordpress/wp-content/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-content/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))

- url: /wp-admin/(.+)
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/\1
  secure: always

- url: /wp-admin/
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/index.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-login.php
  script: wordpress/wp-login.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-cron.php
  script: wordpress/wp-cron.php
  login: admin

- url: /xmlrpc.php
  script: wordpress/xmlrpc.php

- url: /wp-(.+).php
  script: wordpress/wp-\1.php

- url: /(.+)?/?
  script: wordpress/index.php
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Does the AppEngine console show any log output? What does your app.yaml file look like?

Comment: Edited responding to your queries.  Thanks.